# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

Tags: c, compilation

I'm writing a program that builds and runs on my linux box without any issues. I intend to run this on another system where I have no control over the dependencies installed, so my aim is to statically link everything. However, I get the above error even when I pass the following flags during compilation. This is what automake generated when I passed `-static` in `LDFLAGS`

```
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link /usr/bin/clang-9 -g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer -fsanitize=address -Wall -static -o fuzzer fuzzer.o -lpthread -lm -lnsl -lresolv
```

alternatively

```
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link /usr/bin/clang-9 -g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer -fsanitize=address -Wall -lstdc++ -static-libgcc -o fuzzer fuzzer.o -lpthread -lm -lnsl -lresolv
```

Same results.

In addition, I also tried to use the `-static` flag and met with same results

```
root@e143b56f4f87:*****# ldd fuzzer
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4b7a8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe2d009d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe2cfe7e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe2cfae0000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fe2cf8c6000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fe2cf6ab000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe2cf4a3000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe2cf29f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe2cf087000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe2cec96000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe2d0426000)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire command line you're using to link?

Comment: Adding `-Wl,--trace` to your link command may also be informative.

Comment: But if this project is pure C, why are you including `-lstdc++` in your link command at all?

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the question with more info. I also removed the question. This target is for a libFuzzer build and its likely the libFuzzer required stdc++.

Comment: Yeah, I think `-fsanitize=fuzzer` is the key here, since AFAIK its use means you are building a very different program than if you compiled `fuzzer.o` alone.  (I wish you hadn't omitted to mention that in the initial question!)